# Binary Search CompareTo Java

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, binary-search, compareto

I'm trying to use a binary search on an Object Array. I'm using object because for one instance I may have a set of strings or `ints`. I'm currently stuck at implementing my `compareTo` method, not really sure of what the next step would be. 
Here is what I have so far -

```
public static int binarySearch(Object[] items, Comparable target, int first, int last){

    if(first > last)
        return -1; // Base case for unsuccessful search
    else{
        int middle = (first + last) / 2; // Next probe index.
        int compResult = target.compareTo(items[middle]);
        if(compResult == 0)
            return middle; // Base case for unsuccessful search.
        else if (compResult <0)
            return binarySearch(items, target, first, middle -1);
        else
            return binarySearch(items, target, middle + 1, last);
    }
}
public static int binarySearch(Object[] items, Comparable target){
    return binarySearch(items, target, 0, items.length -1);
}
@Override
public int compareTo(T obj) {

    return 0;
}
public static void main(String[] args){
String[] names = {"Caryn", "Debbie", "Dustin", "Elliot", "Jacquie", "Jonathan", "Rich"};

    int myName = binarySearch(names, "Dustin");
```

I'm getting an error when I call binarySearch it says The method binarySearch(Object[], Comparable) in the type FiveThree is not applicable for the arguments (String[], String). I know its because my `CompareTo` is empty right now, but I don't know how to make "Dustin" or whatever parameter I put second a Comparable rather than string. Also if I cast object in front of names it only recognizes it only as an Object not an Object[].
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using raw types rather than generics?

Comment: I guess that's bad on my part so should i change it to something like   List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Caryn", "Debbie", "Dustin", "Elliot", "Jacquie", "Jonathan", "Rich");

Comment: @jumpman8947 No. RealSkeptic meant you should not use the raw type `Comparable`. Using an array is fine.

Comment: Thanks pbabcdefp, I see what your are saying now and the answser below ties it all up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution essentially works.

> I'm trying to use a binary search on an Object Array. I'm using object because for one instance I may have a set of strings or ints

That suggests you should use generics, rather than `Object[]`. If you do this, you will have to use `Integer[]` rather than `int[]` because Java generics do not work for primitive types.

There is no need to write a `compareTo` method because `String` and `Integer` already implement `Comparable`.

I replaced `Object` with `T` (where `T extends Comparable<T>`) and it just worked. This program prints `2` as it should.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearch(T[] items, T target, int first, int last){

    if(first > last)
        return -1; // Base case for unsuccessful search
    else{
        int middle = (first + last) / 2; // Next probe index.
        int compResult = target.compareTo(items[middle]);
        if(compResult == 0)
            return middle; // Base case for unsuccessful search.
        else if (compResult <0)
            return binarySearch(items, target, first, middle -1);
        else
            return binarySearch(items, target, middle + 1, last);
    }
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int binarySearch(T[] items, T target){
    return binarySearch(items, target, 0, items.length -1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Caryn", "Debbie", "Dustin", "Elliot", "Jacquie", "Jonathan", "Rich"};

    int myName = binarySearch(names, "Dustin");
    System.out.println(myName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks i knew I was close I was just stuck wondering if had to do any extra implementation on CompareTo, or if I had to change something else.

Comment: When try to fix it on my computer i get "The method binarySearch(T[], T) in the type FiveThree<T> is not applicable for the arguments (String[], String)" For some reason its only taking names and "Dustin" as only strings.

Comment: My apologies, I had wrote an interface and named it comparable and that was screwing things up, I deleted it and your code works. Thanks a million.